# Can't get the intended Data in mongoose nested object find() despite using right syntax

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

From the following piece of code

```
    const checkAccess = await Access.find(); //Access is the database model

    console.log({ checkAccess });

    const findApi = await Access.find({ api: { name: "addAd" } });

    console.log({ findApi });
```

I get this result:

```
    {
  checkAccess: [ { api: [Object], _id: 608be204606f70333894fafc, __v: 0 } ]
}

{ findApi: [] }
```

There exists `name` inside the `api: [Object]`, but as seen above `findApi = await Access.find({ api: { name: "addAd" } });` returns `null` even when there is a `name:"addAd"` in my database. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: your query will search for exact api object, just try `{ "api.name": "addAd" }` to search specific field in array.